# Reference request for a preprint by Effros-Ruan

Tags: reference-request, paper-request, operator-spaces

I am not sure this question is appropriate for this site, but here goes. If not, please let me know and I will delete the question.

In my literature search, I came across the following reference:

"Operator convolution algebras: an approach to quantum groups, preprint" by Effros and Ruan (1991).

I'm not able to access to find this preprint online. Does someone have a PDF/copy of this preprint they can share?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure that requests for filesharing are appropriate for MO, but in this case I think I can justify it to myself, because the preprint you refer to was (probably) the one that became the following article:

> E. G. Effros, Z.-J. Ruan,  *Operator Space Tensor Products and Hopf Convolution Algebras.*
> [Journal of Operator Theory 50 (2003) no. 1 131--156.](https://jot.theta.ro/jot/archive/2003-050-001/2003-050-001-007.html)

JOT has a moving paywall, so this article is old enough to be freely available.

Quoting from the introduction of the paper:

> Approximately ten years ago the authors showed that one can define Hopf
> algebraic operations on non-commutative $L^1$-spaces by using the operator space projective and extended Haagerup tensor products. These results were circulated in an unpublished manuscript...

> Since an increasing number of authors have referred to the manuscript, we
> believe that it would be useful to make this material available to a wider audience. We have modified the paper in several ways...